# How to correct the center of a view after extending it under navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, storyboard, swift2

In this view controller, i have a navigation bar, an mkmapview, and a collection view. I have the following code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class PhotoAlbumViewController: UIViewController {
    var annotation: VTAnnotation!
    var span: MKCoordinateSpan!

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
        mapView.clipsToBounds = false
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        mapView.userInteractionEnabled = false
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: annotation.coordinate, span: span)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: false)

    }
}
```

If my MKMapView is set up to sit between the Navigation bar and the Collection View in Storyboard, then the pin will be centered as desired. But I don't get to show the translucency of the navigation bar.

[image: 1]

If my MKMapView is set up to sit under the navigation bar, I can show the translucency of the navigation bar, but the pin is now off center.

[image: 1]

How can I get the pin to show up in the center of the visible area, and show the translucency of the navigation bar?

I feel like this should be in the documentations. but I have been looking everywhere with no luck, maybe I don't know the keywords to search for.

Comment: After mapview is being layout-ed, you should consider it's new visible portion. Try to change map region after 'viewDidLayoutSubviews'.

Comment: In mapkit there's methods to calculate coordinate for a piont in a view, and vise-versa - this is the way to go though it. Unfortunately I have no chance to play with code right now. If you won't get your annotation to a right place - poke me back - we'll try to move it :)

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with this same issue and managed to solve it by adding some top padding to the `MKMapView` using the `setVisibleMapRect(_:edgePadding:animated:)` method:

```
    let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: annotation.coordinate, span: span)

    // 1. Set the Region
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: false)

    // 2. Store the currently visible area
    let currentMapRect = mapView.visibleMapRect

    // 3. Store the sum of the navigation bar height and the top safe area inset
    var topPadding: CGFloat = 0
    if let safeAreaTopInset = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.top,
        let navigationBarHeight = navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height {
        topPadding = safeAreaTopInset + navigationBarHeight
    }

    // 4. Add the top padding to the map's visible area
    let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: topPadding, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
    mapView.setVisibleMapRect(currentMapRect, edgePadding: padding, animated: true)

    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```